# Attachment sent as encoded text

Tags: php, email

I am trying to forward the attachment sin my email to another account automatically using this script and swift mailer library. Thing seems to be working for certain extent but the attachments are sent as encoded text. I wanted to send the attachments as it is. I am new to php and unable to figure out where the issue is. Please help me.

```
<?php
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';
$hostname = '{imap.asd.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'abc@as.com';
$password = 'ppwppw';

/* try to connect */
$connection = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Tiriyo: ' . imap_last_error());

ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');

function Message_Parse($id)

{

global $connection;

    if (is_resource($connection))
    {
        $result = array
        (
            'text' => null,
            'html' => null,
            'attachments' => array(),
        );

                $structure = imap_fetchstructure($connection, $id, FT_UID);

        if (is_array($structure) && array_key_exists('parts', $structure))
        {
            foreach ($structure->parts as $key => $part)
            {
                if (($part->type >= 2) || (($part->ifdisposition == 1) && ($part->disposition == 'ATTACHMENT')))
                {
                    $filename = null;

                    if ($part->ifparameters == 1)
                    {
                        $total_parameters = count($part->parameters);

                        for ($i = 0; $i < $total_parameters; $i++)
                        {
                            if (($part->parameters[$i]->attribute == 'NAME') || ($part->parameters[$i]->attribute == 'FILENAME'))
                            {
                                $filename = $part->parameters[$i]->value;

                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (is_null($filename))
                        {
                            if ($part->ifdparameters == 1)
                            {
                                $total_dparameters = count($part->dparameters);

                                for ($i = 0; $i < $total_dparameters; $i++)
                                {
                                    if (($part->dparameters[$i]->attribute == 'NAME') || ($part->dparameters[$i]->attribute == 'FILENAME'))
                                    {
                                        $filename = $part->dparameters[$i]->value;

                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $result['attachments'][] = array
                    (
                        'filename' => $filename,
                        'content' => str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', trim(imap_fetchbody($connection, $id, ($key + 1), FT_UID))),
                    );
                }

                else
                {
                    if ($part->subtype == 'PLAIN')
                    {
                        $result['text'] = imap_fetchbody($connection, $id, ($key + 1), FT_UID);
                    }

                    else if ($part->subtype == 'HTML')
                    {
                        $result['html'] = imap_fetchbody($connection, $id, ($key + 1), FT_UID);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        foreach ($part->parts as $alternative_key => $alternative_part)
                        {
                            if ($alternative_part->subtype == 'PLAIN')
                            {
                                echo '<h2>' . $alternative_part->subtype . ' ' . $alternative_part->encoding . '</h2>';

                                $result['text'] = imap_fetchbody($connection, $id, ($key + 1) . '.' . ($alternative_key + 1), FT_UID);
                            }

                            else if ($alternative_part->subtype == 'HTML')
                            {
                                echo '<h2>' . $alternative_part->subtype . ' ' . $alternative_part->encoding . '</h2>';

                                $result['html'] = imap_fetchbody($connection, $id, ($key + 1) . '.' . ($alternative_key + 1), FT_UID);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        else
        {
            $result['text'] = imap_body($connection, $id, FT_UID);
        }

        $result['text'] = imap_qprint($result['text']);
        $result['html'] = imap_qprint(imap_8bit($result['html']));

        return $result;

    }

    return false;
}

 $emails = imap_search($connection,'ALL');
  rsort($emails);

 foreach($emails as $email_number) {

$result = Message_Parse($email_number);
$data = $result['attachments'];
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$attachment = Swift_Attachment::newInstance($data, 'recorded.mp3', 'audio/mp3');
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('new messaeg')
  ->setFrom(array('aaa@bbb.com' => 'name'))
  ->setTo(array('aaa@ccc.com'))
  ->setBody($result['text'], 'Here is the message itself')
  ->attach($attachment);

  $result1 = $mailer->send($message);

?>
```

Comment: Still I think i dodnt get a proper answer to y question

Comment: Then provide more information.  Specifically, answer the questions that have been posed to you.

Answer (score 0):

What is $data after `$data = $result['attachments'];`?  Think it is an attachment container object of some sort.  You might need to dig in a little more to get the right property (the attachment) to then reattach it.  See: http://dev.kayako.com/browse/SWIFT-2341

Comment: Also just occurred to me.  You might not be unpacking the attachment correctly.  Your mention of 'encoded text' makes me think you might want to read some [RFC's](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2045).  Specifically in regard to mime and base64 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look right:

```
$data = $result['attachments'];
...
$attachment = Swift_Attachment::newInstance($data, 'recorded.mp3', 'audio/mp3');
```

When you create an attachment with this method, I think `$data` is supposed to be a string that contains the contents of the attachment. But `$result['attachments']` is an array of all the attachments in the original message. It seems like you should be looping through these attachments, creating a separate Swift_Attachment for each of them. You also should save the filename and content type from the original message, not hard-code them to recorded.mp3 and audio/mp3 (unless the application ensures that this is all there will be).

As for them being encoded -- MP3's aren't plain text, so what do you expect?

Comment: Thanks.  But i am helpless in taking this forward.